# Corrupted data when converting from void* to struct that contains QString

Tags: c++, qt, casting, void-pointers

I have a class that is a resource manager and keep the data in a map of <`QString`,`void*`> and the class looks like this:

```
template <typename R>
class ResourceManager
{
public:
    ResourceManager() = default;

    template <typename T>
    void set(const R& name, T& object);

    template <typename T>
    T get(const R& name);

private:
    QHash<R, void*> m_objectsMap;
};

template <typename R>
template <typename T>
void ResourceManager<R>::set(const R& name, T& object) {
    m_objectsMap.insert(name, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&object));
}

template <typename R>
template <typename T>
T ResourceManager<R>::get(const R& name) {
    auto it = m_objectsMap.find(name);

    if (it == m_objectsMap.end()) throw std::invalid_argument("The item doesn't exists");

    return *static_cast<T*>(it.value());
}
```

I have this struct:

```
struct UserData {
    QString username = "";
    QString permissions = "";

    QString  token = "";
    qint64   lastTimeUsed = 0;

    UserData() {}
};
```

And in the following function I set it up:

```
void f() {
    UserData userData;
    userData.username    = userStruct.username;
    userData.permissions = userStruct.permissions;
    userData.token       = token;
    userData.updateLastTimeUsed();

    qDebug() << "[Users][actionCheckToken]userData='" << userData.toString() << "'";

    client.getResourceManager()->set<UserData>(USER_RESOURCEMANAGER_USERDATA_KEY, userData);
}
```

If I call `get` right after I set it up it works, but If I call it later, in another function I receive `SIGSEGV`:

```
1   std::__atomic_base<int>::load                  atomic_base.h       396 0x55555556500e 
2   QAtomicOps<int>::load<int>                     qatomic_cxx11.h     227 0x55555556500e 
3   QBasicAtomicInteger<int>::load                 qbasicatomic.h      103 0x555555563e5e 
4   QtPrivate::RefCount::ref                       qrefcount.h         55  0x5555555624a6 
5   QString::QString                               qstring.h           958 0x5555555629a9 
6   Users::UserData::UserData <- my struct         Users.hpp           26  0x555555578cf1 
7   ResourceManager<QString>::get<Users::UserData> ResourceManager.hpp 36  0x555555578df4 
8   [function from where I call]
```

I've checked that my pointers/references to be valid, and they are and also points to the right location(the same resource manager) but I don't know why it crash, but if I call right after I call `set` it works.

Here how the function I call later looks like:

```
void b(Client& client) {
    qDebug() << "[Users][userIsLogged]Called" << "clientID='" + client.getID() + "'";

    auto userData = client.getResourceManager()->get<UserData>(USER_RESOURCEMANAGER_USERDATA_KEY);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: You are storing a pointer to local variable, `userData` is local inside `f`, when `f` ends, `userData` is destroyed, so your resouce manager holds dangling pointer..

Comment: Don’t store pointers you acquire with `&` for later use.

Comment: Yes, I can see now the problem. How should I fix my `ResourceManager`, or I should I store data of multiple/unknown types? Or should I serialize/deserialize everything I store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that your `ResourceManager` is too generalized. Look at its name: It *manages resources*. That means it needs to be able to *own resources*, that means to *take*, *release* and ***destroy*** the resources its supposed to manage.

Your resource manager only stores and retrieves references (here: void* pointers) to some external resources. In this form it would be better named `ResourceDictionary`, which implies that ownership stays outside and the user / caller is responsible to handle the lifetime of the objects.

Now, to transform what you have into a true *resource manager*, there is some crucial data missing: The *type* of the resource. Without knowing *what* is stored in the `void *`, you can't destroy (= safely delete) it.

But you want your resource manager to be templated, so I suggest this approach:

1. Create an abstract base container, let's say `struct tAbstractContainer`. Beware that it needs a virtual destructor!
2. For each type that you want to store, derive a container from that base, e.g. `struct tQStringContainer : tAbstractContainer { QString string; };`
3. Let your resource manager store pointers (hint: make your life easier and avoid raw pointers in favor of smart pointers) of that abstract base container.

   1. If you want raw pointers, you will need to adapt your `set()` function and also implement a destructor and assignment + copy (Rule of Three / Five).
   2. If you want smart pointers, choose the type of pointer wisely.

Now you can put (almost) any data into your manager and it will be correctly destroyed.

For your `UserData` you'd create a `struct tUserDataContainer : tAbstractContainer { UserData userdata; };`. In `f()` you'd create an instance of that container and fill its data accordingly, then throwing it into your manager.